# How to tell Mono to compile for ARM64 when compiling C# under WSL (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, mono, windows-subsystem-for-linux, arm64

I am trying to set up a programming environment on my Windows on ARM Device. Because I have not found any directly compatible ARM64 Compilers for Windows, I decided to install mono under WSL2 Ubuntu. It all works fine. When compiling it throws an .exe and i can execute it on my device! But some how it has to be possible to tell mono if it should be an x64, x86, ARM or ARM64. And how can i know, which of these ive got!
I compile it using `mcs FILE.cs` in the WSL terminal.

Comment: 1) Stop using Mono and switch to .NET Core. `dotnet publish` allows you to publish binaries for ARM64 (.NET Core 3.0 and above). 2) If you insist Mono, the compiler won't target ARM64. You will need Mono ARM64 runtime on the device to execute that .exe file, or use AOT to generate ARM64 native executable.

Comment: Okay - thanks! Due to .NET 5.0 preview its even possible to find a SDK native on arm64. I installed it via the PowerShell and the Script provided at the .net page

Comment: Correct. You will find .NET Core/.NET 5 offers you much cleaner an ecosystem to dive into. Enjoy the journey.